# Displaying table values by proportion in R

Tags: r

I have a table in **R**, and I would like to change each row so that the numbers come up proportionally as opposed to the total quantity.

For example, if my first row is
2,2,0
I want to make it
.5,.5,0

Similarly, if a row is 
4,15,1
I want to make it
.2,.75,.05

Is there a way to do this to the entire table at once?  I know this is probably pretty easy but I've been working on it for a long time.

Comment: How do you want each row to be normalized?  In your first row it sums to 1, but in your second row it sums to 1.45.

Comment: If you actually have a table, i.e., an object of class `table`, then use `prop.table`. You should share data because any answer with code will depend on the way you're storing it... matrix, data.frame, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# sample data
a <- rbind(c(2,2,0), c(4,15,1))


# solution
a / apply(a, 1, sum)
#  [,1] [,2] [,3]
#b  0.5 0.50 0.00
#a  0.2 0.75 0.05
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data is a matrix,

```
my_data = matrix(rpois(12, lambda = 5), nrow = 4)
```

then this is one way to do it:

```
my_data / rowSums(my_data)
```

Comment: +1 This is likely better than my answer, as `rowSums` is a lot faster than `apply` with `FUN=sum`, as the [help page for `rowSums`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html) mentions.